# Clickable items in TableRow in TableLayout in Android

Tags: android

I want to have different rows, each containing multiple TextViews (I made my own extension of the TextView class, called Chip in my code). I create the Chips and the tablerows dynamically. My problem is that when I add the Chips to the TableRow (and the row to the TableLayout), I can no longer click on them. I  have tried to make both the TableLayout and the TableRow clickable, but with no luck. The idea is that each TableRow should contain a different number of Chips, depending on how many it can show on the screen (the Chips will each have different text). I have tried looking at similar questions here, but I could not find any solutions that I could use in my case.

Below is my XML code for the TableLayout

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1"
    android:id="@+id/tabletest">
</TableLayout>
```

And here is the Java code

```
 LinearLayout test = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lineartest);
 TableLayout ll = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabletest);
 TableRow row= new TableRow(this);
 TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
 row.setLayoutParams(lp);

 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Chip c1 = new Chip(this);
    c1.setText("Hey I'm " + i); 
    c1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Chip view = (Chip) v;
            if (view.is_stateChanged()) {
                    view.set_selected(false);
            } else {
                view.set_selected(true);
            }
            view.set_stateChanged(!view.is_stateChanged());
        }
    });
    row.addView(c1);
 }
 ll.addView(row);
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or do I have to find out which row is being clicked, and then via tags trigger the correct clickEvent for the clicked Chip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try to implement Listener like this

LinearLayout test = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lineartest);
 TableLayout ll = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabletest);
 TableRow row= new TableRow(this);
 TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
 row.setLayoutParams(lp);

 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Chip c1 = new Chip(this);
    c1.setText("Hey I'm " + i); 
    c1.setOnClickListener(new Listener(c1));
    row.addView(c1);
 }
 ll.addView(row);
 }
 class Listener implements View.OnClickListener
    {
    Chip view;
    Listener(Chip view)
    {
    this.view = view;
    }

     @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          if (view.is_stateChanged()) {
                    view.set_selected(false);
            } else {
                view.set_selected(true);
            }
            view.set_stateChanged(!view.is_stateChanged());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! Also looks a lot nicer with the extra class.